# Karate - how to use param from response to test child endpoints

Tags: testing, automated-tests, karate

I have a parent URL that returns an array of objects with id and slug, this is dynamically generated because it depends of the user (test env). After getting this data, how can I dynamically call each element object from an array and make another request ?

Example :

```
Scenario: parent
  Given url 'posts'
  Then Status 200
  * assert response.status == true
```

Example url/posts returns a data of array of objects :

```
[
  {id: 6, slug: 'my-post-6'},
  {id: 23, slug: 'example-test-23'},
  {id: 133, slug: 'another-test-133'},
]
```

Then I want to make a get request to every object like so : url 'posts/' data.slug

How can I do this ?

```
GET url 'posts/my-post-6'
// Validate schema
GET url 'posts/example-test-23' 
// Validate schema
GET url 'posts/another-test-133' 
// Validate schema
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karate's `call` keyword auto-loops over a JSON array of objects. Refer the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#data-driven-features

You can try this simple example:

```
Feature:

Scenario:
* def data = [{ slug: 'one'}, { slug: 'two'}]
* call read('@called') data

@called @ignore
Scenario:
* url 'https://httpbin.org/anything'
* path slug
* method get
```

This is getting improved in future versions, refer: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1905 (available now in 1.3.0.RC2)

Comment: But I do not have the data = [{ slug: 'one'}, { slug: 'two'}], only after the first request.

Comment: @rocket_moon I know, so instead of `data` use `response`. I just gave you a hard coded example.

Comment: is not working, for some reason the calls inside the ```@called @ignore``` are not being authenticated with background def session = call read('../Auth.feature')

Comment: @rocket_moon just call a second feature file with the background you want. also refer the docs for auth to be sure: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#http-header-manipulation - I have no other ideas

Comment: Hey, its a bug in karate (I will report this in github), I manage to figure it out. The variables are being overlaped between scenarios